# Computer Touchscreen and mouse not working anymore

Tags: drivers, mouse

Alright, for this one I literally tried everything. One day, in the middle of the day the touch screen and mouse went from working to not working at all. Currently I am using a wireless logitech mouse and my touch screen's been working ever since I bought this laptop three years ago. Then they simultaneously just stopped working. I've been researching this topic for the last three days and I tried everything I could find, including trying to update the drivers for both(Windows tells me they're already updated and it cannot find anything online, because it's 'updated already'), I downloaded DriverEasy, and it still didn't work after I downloaded. Also, every time I go to driver manager both the touch screen and the mouse is listed under 'other devices' and they both have a yellow warning sign(even though Windows tells me everything's updated when I go and try to update, and not in their respective categories, which is very weird. It says driver unavailable and I have no idea what to do for this one, because it seemed like something in my computer just said, "I'm rejecting all external devices from now on", although I tried my headphones out this morning and that works.

But the main issue is the mouse and the touch screen. The touch screen is a definite brain scratcher for me though.

I am working in Windows 10 and no update occurred between the times it was still working to the time it stopped working.

Comment: Instead of "updating" the drivers, you could try uninstalling then reinstalling the drivers. You could also see if there is a relevant restore point to roll back to.

Comment: Dang, no cigar.

Well, I'll just hope for some miracle. What happened was that when I reinstalled them, they re-appeared under the 'other devices' tab.